# Windows Sensor API - Unresolved external symbol for CLSID

Tags: c++, winapi, linker, windows-10, sensors

Using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2013, I am putting together a sensor manager by following the programming tutorial from Microsoft's sensor API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sensorsapi/sensor-api-programming-guide).

It says to include `Propsys.lib` and `PortableDeviceGuids.lib`, but I do not see them in `C:\Windows\System32`; I only see `.dll` extensions of the libraries.

So instead, I included `propsys.dll, Sensorsapi.dll, PortableDeviceApi.dll,` and `PortableDeviceTypes.dll`.
Also, after including the appropriate header files, I seem to have proper reference to all Sensor API functions.

However on build, it gives the `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_SensorManager, _CLSID_PortableDeviceKeyCollection` error. So it seems that the `.dlls` that I have used are not appropriate substitutions. So for Windows 10, where are the applicable dependencies stored in?

**UPDATE**:

I found the corresponding `.lib` files under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib`, but even after including them in the `Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`, it gives me the same errors.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but the symbols are (or should be) defined in the .lib files, not the .dlls.

Comment: That seems to be the problem, do you by any chance know why the .lib files would not be in the Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: Alas, I do not, sorry.

Comment: FWIW PortableDeviceGuids.lib, sensorsapi.lib and propsys.lib are included in the Windows 10 SDKs (see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\<version>\um\<architecture>`) so in this case the issue was why VS2013 couldn't find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CLSID_SensorManager` in defined in `sensorsapi.h`. To use it you must link to the associated library file: Sensorsapi.lib.

You can add library via project->properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct, you can also use

```
#pragma comment(lib,"sensorsapi.lib")
```

inside any source file.